# Unity3D & C# Parse Large File Line By Line Without Making UI Freeze And Update Unity Slider With Progress

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, parsing, slider

I have a large dataset of about 120,000 entries and I would like to parse it line by line.

```
    private void readDataset()
    {
        totalEntries = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
        entriesRead = 0;
        statusSlider.maxValue = totalEntries;
        statusSlider.minValue = entriesRead;
        statusSlider.value = entriesRead;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                entriesRead++;
                statusSlider.value = entriesRead;
                ...
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, with the code shown above, the UI freezes and only starts responding when the parsing has finished. This means, the slider jumps from 0% to 100% and the program just hangs in between.

Is it possible to run this without blocking the main UI thread and also refresh the slider each time the while loop iterates?

Comment: I'm not too experienced with unity but, it looks like your storing `statusSlider.value = entriesRead;` with every iteration. It should only be `entriesRead++` and with it already referenced it should populate the `statusSlider.value` dynamically.

Comment: Yes, but as it is reading the dataset the program just hangs and the slider doesn't change until the dataset is fully parsed, once the dataset is fully parsed the slider jumps to 100%.

Comment: yup, then that may very well be the culprit. As the process is running the `statusSlider.value = entriesRead;` keeps getting "re-assigned" it should be initialized once and be referring dynamically; with every iteration the value is incremented (i.e., give the loading affect). It's jumping to 100% because thats the last value assigned.

Comment: I usually put code into a backgroundworker to prevent freezing.

Comment: Please provide a complete code .. from the comments on an answer here it seems you are calling this from an Editor script? Describe your exact usecase ... Also: You do `ReadLines` which already reads the entire file once so using the StreamReader after that is extremely redundant! At least the first can happen in a thread if you really need the count before reading line by line again ... Use a thread and already store the returned lines ... FileIO is very expensive!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Those will not block the UI.

So, in your case you can do this;

```
private void StartReading() 
{
    StartCoroutine(ReadDataSet());
}

private IEnumerator ReadDataSet()
{
    totalEntries = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
    entriesRead = 0;
    statusSlider.maxValue = totalEntries;
    statusSlider.minValue = entriesRead;
    statusSlider.value = entriesRead;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            entriesRead++;
            statusSlider.value = entriesRead;
            ...
            ...
            Debug.Log($"Current Line {entriesRead}, ({(entriesRead/totalEntries)*100f}%)");
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

There you will wait for a new frame after reading each line, also it will print the current line and the % of the total.

Comment: Hi, is this possible to do without creating a gameobject in the editor and assigning this script? the readDataset() method is in a class called Dataset, I can make this class inherit monobehaviour, is that enough?

Comment: Hi, you can use threads instead. But you have to be careful to call any Unity element from that thread. I mean, if you use threads and you want to update your slider the 'easy' (but incorrect) way to do it, is inside the `while` set a new value on your slide object. This will case unity to crash. But you can update an integer (or float, etc..) and have a method (or coroutine, or inside an Update) where the slider reads the value that  was updated by the thread.

Comment: Another option (but maybe less direct) is using another class that can run coroutines for you, another easy (but not 100% correct) way is to have a singleton that inherits from MonoBehaviour that exists in your game and you can call from anywhere.

Comment: haha, or the last option, your MonoBehavior controller (which has the slider reference) can run the coroutine (ie, call StartCoroutine) and your coroutine can be defined in your Dataset class.

Comment: Hi, I just tried the coroutine way but it seems extremely slow. If I'm using the normal method, it hangs for a few seconds then shows 100%. If I turn the method into a coroutine, it takes several minutes just to get to 25%.

Comment: I like the option where I create a singleton class where I can run coroutines from :-). Threads is another good option but unfortunately, Unity UI is completely incompatible with it.

Comment: Unity Ui is incompatible with threads, but you can still read a variable (let's say, an integer). And a thread can update that variable. That should be faster than waiting for a new frame ('yield null'). Also, another option is to wait for a new frame after a few lines. (`if (entriesRead % 5 == 0) { yield return null;}`

Comment: You could use a `StopWatch` in order to wait about `1/60` seconds before you yield .. this way you have the maximum lines parsed while keeping about 60 fps... However depending a lot on what exactly you do there you might rather want to use a thread ...